# R YaleToolKit Sparklines x-axis showing numbers NOT dates

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a sparkline using the YaleToolKit:

```
library(YaleToolkit)
BusinessDate<-c("01-01-2014","01-02-2014","01-03-2014","01-04-2014","01-05-2014")
Corn<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
Wheat<-c(2,1,0,10,15)
risk<- data.frame(BusinessDate, Corn, Wheat)
risk

BusinessDate    Corn Wheat
1   01-01-2014    1     2
2   01-02-2014    2     1
3   01-03-2014    3     0
4   01-04-2014    4    10
5   01-05-2014    5    15

library(gdata)
temp<-as.Date(risk$BusinessDate)
indx<-which(getDay(temp)!="01")
CustomAxis<-as.character(temp)
CustomAxis[indx]<-" "
 SparkLinesCustom(risk[,c("Corn", "Wheat")], times=as.numeric(risk$BusinessDate),      customlabel = CustomAxis )
```

I am trying to only show the first day of the month but the axis is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into the code of the function and made a quick fix that should work for this case at least, but hasn't been tested/have error handling, so beware if trying to use it in other ways.

I made a new function `sparklinescustom` edited from the original code and added a `customlabel` argument that should take a character vector of the length of your data frame and apply them to your x-axis

```
sparklinescustom = function (ss, times = NULL, overlap = FALSE, yscale = NULL, buffer = unit(0, 
                                                                          "lines"), buffer.pars = NULL, IQR = NULL, ptopts = NULL, 
          yaxis = TRUE, xaxis = "exterior", labeled.points = NULL, 
          point.labels = NULL, label.just = c(1.2, 0.5), frame.pars = NULL, 
          line.pars = gpar(lwd = 1), outer.margin = unit(c(5, 4, 4, 
                                                           2), "lines"), outer.margin.pars = NULL, main = NULL, 
          sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, lcol = NULL, new = TRUE, customlabel = NULL) 
{
  if (is.null(ss) && !is.null(outer.margin.pars)) {
    grid.rect(gp = outer.margin.pars)
    return()
  }
  if (!is.data.frame(ss)) 
    stop("ss is not a data frame")
  if (is.null(times)) 
    times <- 1:nrow(ss)
  if (length(times) != nrow(ss)) 
    stop("the length of times is not the same as the number of observations")
  if (is.list(yscale)) {
    if (length(yscale) != length(ss)) 
      stop("incorrect dimensions of ss and yscale")
    yscales <- yscale
  }
  else {
    yscales <- vector("list", length = length(ss))
    if (is.vector(yscale) && length(yscale) == 2) 
      for (j in 1:length(ss)) yscales[[j]] <- yscale
    else {
      if (is.null(yscale)) {
        yscale <- vector("list", length = length(ss))
        for (j in 1:length(ss)) yscales[[j]] <- range(ss[, 
                                                         j], na.rm = TRUE)
      }
    }
  }
  if (is.null(lcol)) 
    lcol <- rep(1, length(ss))
  if (new) 
    grid.newpage()
  if (!is.null(ss) && !is.null(outer.margin.pars)) 
    grid.rect(gp = outer.margin.pars)
  subvp <- viewport(x = outer.margin[2], y = outer.margin[1], 
                    width = unit(1, "npc") - outer.margin[2] - outer.margin[4], 
                    height = unit(1, "npc") - outer.margin[1] - outer.margin[3], 
                    just = c("left", "bottom"))
  pushViewport(subvp)
  if (!is.null(main)) 
    grid.text(main, x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(1, "npc") + 
                unit(1.5, "lines"), gp = gpar(fontface = 2))
  if (!overlap) {
    panel.layout <- viewport(layout = grid.layout(length(ss), 
                                                  1), xscale = range(times, na.rm = TRUE))
    pushViewport(panel.layout)
    if (!is.null(xaxis) & xaxis == "exterior") {
      if(!is.null(customlabel)){
        grid.xaxis(at = times,label = customlabel)
      }
      else{
        grid.xaxis()
      }
      if (!is.null(xlab)) {
        grid.text(label = xlab, x = unit(0.5, "npc"), 
                  y = unit(-3, "lines"))
      }
      xaxis <- FALSE
      xlab <- NULL
    }
    for (i in 1:length(ss)) {
      pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 1, layout.pos.row = i, 
                            yscale = yscales[[i]]))
      sparkline(s = ss[, i], times = times, ylim = yscales[[i]], 
                buffer = buffer, new = FALSE, ptopts = ptopts, 
                frame.pars = frame.pars, buffer.pars = buffer.pars, 
                yaxis = yaxis, ylab = ylab[i], xaxis = xaxis, 
                xlab = xlab[i], sub = sub[i], IQR = IQR, line.pars = gpar(col = lcol[i]))
      popViewport(1)
      if (xaxis == TRUE || xaxis == "exterior") 
        popViewport(1)
      popViewport(1)
      popViewport()
    }
    popViewport(1)
  }
  else {
    if (!is.null(xaxis) & xaxis == "exterior") {
      grid.xaxis()
      if (!is.null(xlab)) {
        grid.text(label = xlab, x = unit(0.5, "npc"), 
                  y = unit(-3, "lines"))
      }
      xaxis <- FALSE
      xlab <- NULL
    }
    if (length(unique(yscales)) > 1) {
      warning("y-scales are not the same; are you really sure you want to plot all sparklines on the same y-axis?")
    }
    for (i in 1:length(ss)) {
      pushViewport(viewport(y = 0, height = 1, yscale = yscales[[i]], 
                            just = "bottom", default.units = "npc"))
      sparkline(s = ss[, i], times = times, ylim = yscales[[i]], 
                buffer = buffer, new = FALSE, ptopts = ptopts, 
                frame.pars = frame.pars, buffer.pars = buffer.pars, 
                yaxis = yaxis, ylab = ylab[i], xaxis = xaxis, 
                xlab = xlab[i], sub = sub[i], IQR = NULL, line.pars = gpar(col = lcol[i]))
    }
  }
  popViewport(1)
}
```

By copying the above function into your R and then trying:

```
sparklinescustom(risk[,c("Corn", "Wheat")], times=as.numeric(risk$BusinessDate),customlabel = as.character(risk$BusinessDate))
```

We get:
[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: That is awesome. One follow up and I may be pushing it but my real app has 1 year of data and the dates are overlapping and cannot be read. Is there a way to make the dates show my month or week?

Comment: @user3022875 Hm, do you mean you only want a label every x days? You could try generating a character vector to have character values every x days and be empty everywhere else. This could probably be done using a loop/apply and the paste function.

Comment: I added some code to only show the 1st day of teh month but the xaxis comes up blank.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `temp<-as.Date(risk$BusinessDate, format="%m-%d-%Y")` instead of `temp<-as.Date(risk$BusinessDate)`. The dates were being formatted incorrectly, hopefully that fixes everything.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try a `ggplot` alternative.

```
# reshape your data to long format for ggplot
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(risk, id.var = "BusinessDate")

# convert dates to class Date
df$date <- as.Date(df$BusinessDate, format = "%m-%d-%Y")

library(ggplot2)

# to access nice breaks and formatting functions in scale_x_date
# labels = date_format(); breaks = date_breaks()
# see strptime for other date formats
library(scales)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~variable, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b %d") ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`sparklines` only works with numeric `x` and `y` axes, but your date variable is a character. Try converting it to number of days since the earliest day in the data set:

```
# Convert to R's POSIXct
risk$BusinessDate <- strptime(risk$BusinessDate, "%m-%d-%Y")
# Convert to number of days since earliest day in the dataset
risk$BusinessDay <- as.integer(difftime(risk$BusinessDate, min(risk$BusinessDate), unit = 'days'))
```

You can then use this to graph along number of days (unfortunately, the `sparklines` `xlab` parameter does not work as expected, so you can't label the x-values with dates).

```
sparklines(risk[,c("Corn", "Wheat")], times=risk$BusinessDay )
```

[image]